# Instantiate generic class with constructor arguments

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to instantiate this class with reflection:

```
new DbAccess<ProductMoveRequestView>(dbSet);
```

I have found `ProductMoveRequestView` with reflection. I have it as a Type object.

I have tried with Activator, seen through `MakeGenericType` property on Type, and other variations, but I cannot seem to find a way to instantiate this.

---

It is like duplicate reference, but, as I said in the comments, I still have to instantiate it with an argument.

```
Type tableType = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First();
var dbSet = _context.Set(tableType);
Type[] typeArgs = { tableType };
var makeme = typeof(IRepository<>).MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
var o = Activator.CreateInstance(makeme);
```

The dbSet variable should be sent in as argument when creating the o.

---

Solution:(I found later)
That was easier than I hoped.

```
Activator.CreateInstance(makeme, constructor, arguments, here);
```

Sorry guys :) (Hope this helps for anyone else who can't get this to work :)

Comment: Please post the code where you've tried to use the Activator as well.

Comment: @CodeCaster Not 100% sure this is a dupe as he is asking about constructor parameters (though it's pretty trivial to make that step)

Comment: Please post answer separate, it should not be part of question.. :)

Comment: I would love to do that, but I cannot answer my question, because someone thinks it's a duplicate... to a question that did not answer my question...